# how to run function encryption in django

Tags: python, django, encryption, django-views, django-urls

so i have function for encryption in views.py. the file is saved at models. i want to run the function to know if the function is work. but i don't know how to run the function or code in urls.py

here's my views.py :

```
key_bytes = 16
testaudio = Audio_store.objects.all().values_list('audio').last()
key = 'testing'
# Takes as input a 32-byte key and an arbitrary-length plaintext and returns a
# pair (iv, ciphtertext). "iv" stands for initialization vector.
def encrypt(key, testaudio):
    assert len(key) == key_bytes
    print(testaudio)
    print(key)
    # Choose a random, 16-byte IV.
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)

    # Convert the IV to a Python integer.
    iv_int = int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16)

    # Create a new Counter object with IV = iv_int.
    ctr = Counter.new(AES.block_size * 8, initial_value=iv_int)

    # Create AES-CTR cipher.
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)

    # Encrypt and return IV and ciphertext.
    ciphertext = aes.encrypt(testaudio)
    print(iv)
    print(ciphertext)
    return (iv, ciphertext)
```

testaudio got by user add it from html.

Answer (score 0):

Enter `py manage.py shell` in your django root project folder.

Import the function from the app -> models -> funtion_name

run the function in the `manage.py shell`

#### Alternatively:

there are some great ways to use Jupyter Notebooks with django. This allows for you to easily test your code

https://medium.com/ayuth/how-to-use-django-in-jupyter-notebook-561ea2401852